# Error while creating project with strapi and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, strapi, npx

Previously i installed mongo using guide from strapi documentation. If i wrote command

> service mongod status

I get log about working db:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-08 11:38:50 EEST; 41min ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Main PID: 972 (mongod)
CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─972 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

But when i try to create project using command and choosed mongo as database

> npx create-strapi-app my-project

i get error

> ⛔️ Connection test failed: Command failed: yarnpkg --cwd
> /tmp/strapi0b12da72e284 add strapi-connector-mongoose@3.2.1 error An
> unexpected error occurred: "https/strapi-connector-mongoose: Invalid
> URI "https/strapi-connector-mongoose"".

and as result project doesn't create

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by changing registry of npm config. Command for fix:

> npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/